# How do I show that the following is a basis for the weak topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$S(x_0, \epsilon, A^*)=\{x \in X : |f(x) - f(x_0)|< \epsilon \, \forall \, f \in A^*   \}$ Where $A^*$ is a finite subset of the dual space $X'$.

I'm stuck on how to apply the two conditions of basis on the set.

Comment: Isn't this the definition of the weak topology? What is your definition?

Comment: @ThomasE. The definition I'm using is that the topology on $X$ defined by the semi norm $\{pf : f \in X^*\}$ is the weak topology.

Comment: What is $p$ and what do you mean by that set being a semi-norm?

Comment: @Mark: In your previous comment did you mean $\{p_f:f\in X^*\}$, where $p_f(x)=|f(x)|$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, that's what I meant. Apologies, I was typing from my phone and wasn't careful.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this thread useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305808/semi-norms-and-the-definition-of-the-weak-topology