# Neighborhoods of points in the weak topology.

Tags: general-topology

I am having difficulty with the following question. Let $X = c_0$ ($c_0$ — Banach space of sequences converging to zero). What means in this case neighborhood of zero in the weak topology? For example: Let $A_1 = \{x \in c_0: x_1+x_2>-2\}$ ($x_1$ and $x_2$ — coordinates of vector $x$). $A_1$ is a subset of c0, which contain open neighborhood of zero ($V = \{x \in A_1: \lvert x_1\rvert<0.5, \lvert x_2\rvert<0.5\}$). But what in this case is a neighborhood of zero in weak topology?

I know that topology called weaker when open subsets are also open in stronger one.

Comment: "topology called weaker when open subsets are also open in stronger one" is not a definition of the weak topology. Look for instance at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305808 for the definition(s) of the weak topology on a normed vector space, and use that the continuous dual of $c_0$ is $\ell^1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $V$ of $c_0$ is a neighborhood of $0$ for the weak topology iff it contains some set of the form
$$\{x\in c_0\mid |f_1(x)|<1,\dots,|f_n(x)|<1\}$$
for some [continuous linear forms $f_1,\dots,f_n$ on $c_0,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732839) i.e.

$f_k(x)=\sum x_ny_n$ for some $y\in\ell^1.$

E.g. your $A_1$ is a neighborhood of $0$ (your $V$ works, with $n=2,$ but more simply, take $n=1$ and $y=(1/2,1/2,0,0,\dots)$).

Comment: What is ci (cn) here, constant?

Comment: Also if we take n = 1 we got only one f1? (a bit confused about indexes)
If it's right, it means that V contains such x from co, which after mapping by f1 (multiplication by a constant ci (xi =yi/ci?)) and then sum) we got one number which should be < 1 (modulo)? If also yes and ci - constant, it could be almost any sequence of yi, because we can pick up suitable ci for every yi, right?

Comment: Sorry, $c_i$ was a misprint for $x_i$ (of course, since $f_k(x)$ is supposed to depend on $x$ and $y$). I edit. And yes, if $n=1$ there is only one $f_1$ and $y_1$ (which I renamed $f$ and $y$). If $y=(1/2,1/2,0,0,\dots)$ then $f(x)=(x_1+x_2)/2$, so $|f(x)|<1\iff |x_1+x_2|<2\Rightarrow x_1+x_2>-2.$ Is everything clear now?

Comment: Yes, now i understand. Also you say that it works with n = 2. You mean f1 = sum(xn,yn) where y = (1/2, 0, ...) and also f2 = sum(xn,yn), but here y = (0, 1/2, 0, ...)? And last question: you take 1/2 because of condition x1 + x2 > -2, so it can be even 2/3?

Comment: 1) Yes, exactly. 2) Yes, and yes.

Comment: Sorry, do not want to create a new question. I saw some statement that if a subset is closed in weak topology => subset is closed in stronger one. Can i say it in reverse way (<=) ?

Comment: Of course not, otherwise the 2 topologies would be the same.

Comment: But if i know that a set is not closed in stronger: because of necessity, can i say that a set not closed in weak ?

Comment: [?! Yes: look at your  =>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) in you previous comment.